# Orchard CKEditor not rendering on custom text areas

Tags: ckeditor, orchardcms, orchard-modules

I have a custom module that works with a custom data type and part. 
In my edit view I have some textareas but these are no rendered by CKEditor. 
Only BodyPart html text areas are rendered (like in pages & blog posts).
How can I do this?

References: https://orchardckeditor.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor needs to be initialized, either sneak in somewhere this javascript line

```
CKEDITOR.replace(textarea);
```

or append class `ckeditor` for auto-initialization

```
<textarea class="ckeditor"></textarea>
```

---

If it doesn't work you may also need to add script requirement to your edit view

```
Script.Require("CKEditor");
```

Comment: Yes, but in Orchard I don't need to do that for BodyPart, which is being used in content types like blog post or page. And that's because there's a view in CKEditor module called "Body-Html.Editor.cshtml" that does that automatically. I would like to do the same for Orchard custom modules...